# Max bitrate value for Google chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, web, camera, webrtc

I have a simple question.

**What is the current maximum bitrate value supported by Google Chrome browser for web camera ?**

For example, if I have a virtual source with high bitrate output (constant bitrate 50 Mbits)

Would I be able to get all 50 Mbits in my Chrome browser when using this device?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camera's bitrate is irrelevant in this case, since WebRTC is going to encode that information using a video codec that compresses that information anyway.

What matters for WebRTC are 4 separate parameters:

1. The resolution supplied and the one the other end of the session is capable of receiving
2. The frame rate supplied and the one the other end of the session is capable of receiving
3. The network conditions - there's a limit enforced by the network and it is dynamic in nature, so WebRTC will try to estimate it at all times and accommodate to it
4. The maximum bitrate imposed by the participants

WebRTC in its nature will not limit the amount of bandwidth it takes and will try to use as much as it possibly can. That said, the actual bitrate used even without any limits will still depend on (1), (2) and the type of codec being used. It won't reach 50mbps...

For the most part, 2.5mbps will be enough for almost any type of content in WebRTC. 1080p will take up to 4mbps and 4K probably around 15mbps.